# log4net getting ? instead of method name randomly

Tags: log4net

I have .net 4.5.2 applications where i am using log4net 1.2.15.0 version (even in 2.0.8)
I have random behavior that in method name i am getting ? in my text file
I have tried both %M or %method and this behavior reoccur randomly
My Appender setting is

```
 <appender name="MyApp" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
    <file value="..\\Logs\\MyApp.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />    
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
      <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
      <levelMin value="INFO" />
      <levelMax value="FATAL" />
    </filter>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} %10p [%2t] %5c{1}.%method - %m%n" />
      <!-- <conversionPattern value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} %10p [%2t] %5c{1}.%M - %m%n" /> -->
    </layout>
  </appender>
```

Sample output text in log file is
2017-08-22 07:13:08.668       INFO [ 4] ServicesManager.? - Socket connectivity Reply from aaa, is True at socket connectivity attempt 1

Please help me in finding what's the problem

Comment: Can you replicate this with sample code? Like a simple console app using this config.

Comment: Not able to reproduce it on my development machine (windows 10). But our multiple production windows 2012 R2 servers where i have multiple applications (some windows service and couple of WCF applications) it reproduce randomly

Comment: @KamranShahid Have you tried writing a console app and running it from the remote box? Nothing happens randomly, it's more that the triggers might be rare enough to make it difficult to track down.

Answer (score 2):

This is [documented behaviour](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html):

> The following patterns `%type %file %line %method %location %class %C %F %L %l %M` all generate caller location information. Location information uses the System.Diagnostics.StackTrace class to generate a call stack. The caller's information is then extracted from this stack.
>
> StackTrace information will be most informative with Debug build configurations. By default, Debug builds include debug symbols, while Release builds do not. The debug symbols contain most of the file, method name, line number, and column information used in constructing StackFrame and StackTrace objects. StackTrace might not report as many method calls as expected, due to code transformations that occur during optimization.
>
> This means that in a Release build the caller information may be incomplete or may not exist at all! **Therefore caller location information cannot be relied upon in a Release build.**

The documentation also says:

> Generating caller location information is extremely slow. Its use should be avoided unless execution speed is not an issue.

Comment: so it mean's in our Release Build deployed on production there is not way we can guarantee the method name?

Comment: It's very strange. Thanks Stuart

Comment: Well, you _could_ disable code optimizations add/or add `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]` attributes to the methods, but that's a tradeoff I personally woudn't make.

Comment: In my application i have to care about performance a lot so i can't do it there. But it might help other places where performance is not that critical